# How to fix Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-20.04, sql-server-2019

I have installed Sql Server 2019 Developer Edition and mssql-tools on my Ubuntu 20.04 minimal.
I can connect to my localhost with no issue, but when I want to remote to another sql server:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -U <username> -P <password>
```

I face this error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

I has this issue once in Debian 10, and also search the net for solution, so after that I change my `openssl.conf` manually (su permission needed):

```
nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

and add these to my file:

- `ess_cert_id_alg = sha1` under the `[tsa_config1]` heading
- `openssl_conf = default_conf` near the top
- the following at the end:

  [default_conf]

  ssl_conf = ssl_sect

  [ssl_sect]

  system_default = system_default_sect

  [system_default_sect]

  MinProtocol = TLSv1.0

  CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1

I know that `MinProtocol` and `CipherString` are normally set to `TLSv1.2` and `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2`, but as I mentioned once in my Debian 10, I edited my openssl.conf and change `TLSv1.2` to `TLSv1.0` and `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` to `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` and my connection fixed, but in Ubuntu 20.04 minimal not only there wasn't these lines, but also when I insert these manually again I face the same error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

my opnessl version is:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I also downgrade my openssl once to 1.0 but it didn't work either!

I couldn't find anything else so I came here to ask for help, appreciate your help.

Comment: Please refer to the answer provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75732370/4476745

Answer (score 1):

1.1.1m save my life. Install it manually.

The manual installation looks like:

```sh
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/latest.tar.gz -O openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz

tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz

cd openssl-1.1.1m

./config

make

sudo make install

openssl version

sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: This worked for me after trying a bunch of things (including the openssl.cnf updates), I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on AWS - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **-C** option to trust the server certificate:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -U <username> -P <password> -C
```

For more details, please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443215/970830