# [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol]

Tags: python, ubuntu

os: ubuntu 20.04

server SQL server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)

python 3.8

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

Error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I try to modify openssl.conf:

```
oid_section             = new_oids

openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

then reboot

but it cant work.

Answer (score 5):

OS: Ubuntu 20/22

Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded OpenSSL to version 3.0.2, which is more strict in its security policies. So, we need to downgrade the policy settings to fetch the data

Create a config file somewhere (e.g. ~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf with following content:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

Then run your command like this:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf python3 update.py
```

Thanks [plumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) for the reference.

Answer (score 4):

This might be the right approach, but I think you should lower the protocol to TLSv1.0

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

I just hit this problem trying to connect from a Debian 10 with openssl 1.1.1d to a Windows Server 2008 with MSSQL 12 Express.

Lowering the protocol version works directly, no reboot needed.

Comment: Which file to edit to lower the TLS protocol?

Comment: the OpenSSL config file, on Debian/Ubuntu it's probably /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me too. Debian 11 (docker), msodbcsql17

Comment: it works for me too, it is an old sql 2008 database and it is not support any new TLS version, works on docker python:3.10-slim-bullseye with django, message me if need full working setup of this

Answer (score 2):

step1:

nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

```
# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file               = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section             = new_oids

openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

step2:

The manual installation looks like:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/latest.tar.gz -O openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1h
./config
make
sudo make install
openssl version
sudo ldconfig
```

reference:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284658/how-to-fix-microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server-ssl-provider-ssl-choose-cli

Comment: I edited the openssl.cnf, but I am not able to download openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz, it says 404 Not Found. Although I have downloaded openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz somehow, but not able to run  tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz command. Errors:--> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @HemantSah, 'unexpected eof' means the file is corrupt and given you're specifying an output filename it likely means you have a zero-length file.  Try targeting a specific version instead of using 'latest.tar.gz'

Comment: You are right, I am not able to recall correctly, but I installed lower version of openssl in popos(ubunut based) to match with sqlserver driver. that fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by installing this security update from Microsoft:

[Security Update for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 (KB4057113)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56415)

Answer (score -1):

Look for 1.1.1m.tar.gz  - this is the latest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30849623)