# ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086]

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, openssl

I have the following error while trying to connect SQL Server:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate]
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20, PHP 7.4 FPM, nginx.

```
Server  Microsoft SQL Server [11.00.3128
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
    Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
]
```

When I:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserverip:1433 -tls1
```

I get:

> CONNECTED(00000003)

My openssl library version is:

> OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021)

I have tried many things, like forcing system to use TLS1 in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf or nginx configuration to downgrade to tls1.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the TLS protocol version. When SQL Server gets installed it is configured with a self-signed X.509 certificate. If you want to use encrypted connections (with `Encrypt=yes;` in the connection string, which is the default now) you'll either need to 1) get the X.509 certificate's public key from the server and add it to your trusted certificates store on the client or 2) use the `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` setting in your connection string.

Comment: Have a read through the breaking changes in [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228).

Comment: Thank You very much ! It is working know ! Kind Regards

Comment: Hey @Matt could you let me know how you got it to work? I am having the exact same error

Answer (score 66):

As @AlwaysLearning said in the comments, you need to add `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` to your connection string.

So something along the lines of

```
"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=$url;DATABSE=$db;UID=$usr;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
```

should work.

Comment: Just an FYI, I recently encountered this issue and was already using the `TrustServerCertificate=yes` flag, but it still wasn't working. I changed it to `TrustServerCertificate=true` and it started working, for whatever reason.

Comment: For me the same, i had to change ```TrustServerCertificate=yes``` to ```TrustServerCertificate=true```

Answer (score 30):

If you are not using SQL Server command-line tools (sqlcmd or terminal) then make sure to install it from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15

Then add the **-C** option to trust the server certificate.

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -U <username> -P <password> -C
```

Ex:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'YourPassword' -C
```

Or as mentioned in Microsoft Docs:

> Try using the IP address 127.0.0.1 instead. It's possible that
> localhost isn't properly mapped to this address

Ex:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P 'YourPassword' -C
```

List of the available options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-sqlcmd?view=sql-server-ver16#available-options

Comment: So simple. Why doesn't microsoft put this in their instructions?

Answer (score 18):

I was having this same error while using ODBC Driver 18 with sqlalchemy + python 3.9. My solution is the same as @Olsgaard - set the `TrustServerCertificate` parameter to yes. With sqlalchemy, you can set it at the `connect_args` key in `create_engine`:

```
conn_string = ...
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    conn_string,
    connect_args = {
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes"
    }, echo=False)
```

*I figured my answer is relevant since the link to this question pops up first when you google this exact error after encountering it with sqlalchemy ...*

Answer (score 11):

For Laravel (PHP) having this same problem, this can be fixed by adding the following flag in `config/database.php`

> 'trust_server_certificate' => 'true'

Ex:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'trust_server_certificate' => 'true'
    ]
```

Comment: adding this `'trust_server_certificate' => 'true'` solves the issue.

Comment: Important note. In MS docs they use yes/no values when explaining. It might be confusing sometimes:) So in PHP 'trust_server_certificate' => 'true/false' not: 'trust_server_certificate' => 'yes/no'

Answer (score 10):

for  mssql-django database backend , use the config below:

```py
DATABASES['source'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'mssql',
    'NAME': env('SOURCE_DB_NAME'),
    'USER': env('SOURCE_DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': env('SOURCE_DB_PASS'),
    'HOST': env('SOURCE_DB_HOST'),       
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
        'extra_params': "Encrypt=no" #TrustServerCertificate=no
    },
}
```

[ref](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/issues/64)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding TrustServerCertificate=yes; to the connection string on Ubuntu 22.04 I also had to lower the default security level from 2 to 0 in the openssl config file.

```
sudo nvim /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
[system_default_sect]
# CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving my code from my Windows dev machine to our Linux RHEL server, I got the same error. Adding `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` also solved it (as mentioned by @AlwaysLearning and @Olsgaard)

Just make sure to check the Microsoft [RHEL7 Linux installation instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50420) (or distro instructions for your prod env)

Also `DRIVER={{SQL Server}}` may work on Windows dev machine, but on Linux you must specify the odbc version like `DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}}` if you using the `pyodbc` or `pypyodbc` packages when coding in python. You can get the driver information from `odbcinst -q -d`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sqlsrv_connect()` then you need to add `TrustServerCertificate` in your sql info like:

```
$sql_info = array(
    'UID' => 'your_sql_user',
    'PWD' => 'your_password',
    'Database' => 'your_DB_name',
    'TrustServerCertificate' => 1,
);

sqlsrv_connect('your_host_or_ip', $sql_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my python code this worked for me as I didn't need encryption for local dev:

```
conn_str = f'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}; Encrypt=no'
```

`Encrypt=no` is the key.