# Laravel SQL Server Error: ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL

Tags: sql-server, laravel, ssl

Full error I am getting is:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate] (SQL: SHOW TABLES) (View: /var/www/html/uvk/resources/views/index.blade.php)

I do have an SSL certificate and can connect through HTTPs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server\]SSL Provider: \[error:1416F086\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688125/odbc-driver-18-for-sql-serverssl-provider-error1416f086)

Answer (score 15):

Your web server's SSL/TLS certificate has nothing to do with the error message, it's referring to the certificate used by the SQL Server service.

Please refer to [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) which mentions:

> Changes
>
> - BREAKING CHANGE - Default Encrypt to Yes/Mandatory.

ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server both default to the `Encrypt=yes;` connection string option with the goal of improving data security for SQL Server users and developers. Unfortunately, by default, SQL Server instances are installed with self-signed X.509 certificate that are not trusted by any CAs (Certificate Authorities) so most people upgrading to these versions of the drivers are receiving errors similar to yours.

You have three options here:

1. Export the public key portion of the target SQL Server's certificate to a .crt file and import it into the trusted certificate stores of the users that need to connect to it, or
2. Add `TrustServerCertificate=true;` (or `TrustServerCertificate=yes;`, depending on your programming language) to your connection string, so that the server's certificate is accepted without error and allows secure, encrypted connections, or
3. Add `Encrypt=false;` (or `Encrypt=no;`, depending on your programming language) to your connection string. This is the least desirable option as it prevents the connection from being encrypted, meaning that the traffic between your SQL Server and the client can be intercepted and inspected with ease.

Comment: In my case "yes " was not working, so I used TrustServerCertificate=True and It worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Some libraries accessing ODBC/JBDC require `Yes`/`No` settings, others `True`/`False`, so it's definitely worth trying both to see which works. The blog/release notes linked in the answer use both versions.

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning, I was so confused why my server connection just borked for apparently no reason. Seems like since I started using ODBC 18 instead of ODBC 17, I needed to add `TrustServerCertificate=Yes` to the connection string, like you said to do. Now it works again :D

Comment: Hello, I have a similar problem, the message I receive when trying to connect to a database with the parameter TrustServerCertificate=true is "[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error ]". If I set it to false, I get "SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]". It's the same with ODBC 17 and 18. The strange thing is that with other databases I don't have this problem... I'm working on OSX Big Sur. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: As a bonus: the database I can't connect to runs on SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3; while I can connect without problem to a database in SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3, in both cases with self-signed certificates.

Comment: @Drewkenobi I recommend asking a new question for that, providing as much detail as possible. Do the administrators of the SQL Servers to which you're connecting have something against applying Service Packs and Cumulative Updates? 12.0.2000.8 is the original SQL Server 2014 RTM (there have been 3 Service Packs plus four additional Cumulative Updates since then) and 14.0.1000.169 is the original SQL Server 2017 RTM (there have been 29 Cumulative Updates since then).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks for the comment. Good point! I was unaware of this details about the cumulative updates and service packs. I will ask for comments on it. Regards.

Comment: Before anyone else needs to mald about this: "TrustServerCertificate" is only accepted if "Encrypt" exists in the connection string. By default encryption is enabled now with ODBC driver version 18 and just adding TrustServerCertificate without Encrypt will not do the job