# ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server doesn't allow PHP PDO to connect

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I'm in the process of updating our pipeline due to upgrading the required PHP version. In the process I needed to change our MSSQL client to sqlcmd and I installed `msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18 unixodbc-dev`. With this change the SQL driver now requires a valid cert for the SQL to allow connection. With sqlcmd I just needed to add a flag to bypass this, but our automated tests against the MSSQL database aren't allowed to connect with error:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

I've being able to find the same issue for Laravel, but none that would be using PDO for the connection. I've tried passing the following options array to try to add the parameters to the connection that would allow it to ignore the cert validity but no success

```
[
    'trust_server_certificate' => true, // 'TrustServerCertificate' too
    'encrypt' => 'no', // 'Encrypt' => 'yes' as well
]
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: *"With this change the SQL driver now requires a valid cert for the SQL to allow connection."* This isn't quite correct. From ODBC 18 onwards connections are encrypted by default. As a result if you *are* using an encrypted connection and your server doesn't have a valid certificate (such as the default self-signed cert) the connection will fail as it isn't trusted. A workaround is tell the connection string to "trust" the certification, but the "best" solution is to actually ensure you put a valid certificate on the instance.

Comment: This encryption breaking change was well documented with [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) back in Feb-2022. Have you read the release notes and followed those instructions? What didn't work for you? When looking at the [PHP Connection Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options) did you notice that the boolean options use `0` or `1` values, or `false` or `true` (not `'no'` or `'yes'` strings)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I found some connection strings/DNS related to our MSSQL database and added the values in the Laravel question but no success with those either. I'm still trying to figure out if those are used for the connection for it to have any effect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732117/laravel-sql-server-error-odbc-driver-18-for-sql-serverssl-provider-error141

Comment: Okay, looks like our setup doesn't use those configs... Off to see where I need to add it